# Angular- Typescript code running through loop even after reaching return statement

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular and I ran into a problem today. I am displaying an array of JS objects and when I click on a single item, I want a new component to display only the details of that object. I am using a service to hold and do CRUD operations in the array. Below is the code for getServer which finds a single object in the array by id.

```
getServer(id: number) {
  const server = this.servers.find(
    (s) => {
      return s.id === id;
    }
  );
  return server;
}
```

The problem shows up when I click on a single object. The above method is returning an "undefined" object. I tried placing breakpoints in the code and found that even after reaching the **return** statement with the correct object, the code again goes back to the **find** method and runs the arrow function and then returns undefined. Find the screenshots when I clicked the first object (id:1) below:

---

[image: screenshot 1]

---

[image: screenshot 2]

---

[image: screenshot 3]

---

[image: screenshot 4]

---

[image: screentshot 5]

---

[image]

---

getServer is called in another component (ServerComponent).

```
ngOnInit() {
  const id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
  this.server = this.serversService.getServer(id);
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (params:Params)=>{
      this.server = this.serversService.getServer(params["id"]);
    }
  );
}
```

Stackblitz link: https://routing-start.stackblitz.io

Comment: We would have to see where `getServer` is called. It may be called in several places or in a loop.

Comment: would you please reproduce your issue in stackblitz and share the link

Comment: You can check what @ConnorsFan said with the stack section in the debugger

Comment: @Reza stackblitz link: https://routing-start.stackblitz.io

Comment: @ConnersFan I have added the code which calls the getServer. It is called only once and even if it is called in a loop, the method has to return the object to the parent component and then come back again to the service for the next loop iteration. It is not the case here. I have used breakpoints in both places and the app never jumps back to the parent component. It goes to the return statement and immediately jumps back to the top of the method.

Comment: I see that the `return s.id === id` is not called after the return in the stackbliz
`ServersService.prototype.getServer = function (id) {
        var server = this.servers.find(function (s) {
            return s.id === id;
        });
        return server;
    };`

Comment: the problem will be, that `this.server.find` is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getServer method is called by 2 things as commented

```
ngOnInit() {
  const id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
  this.server = this.serversService.getServer(id); // Here with id as number
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (params:Params)=>{
      this.server = this.serversService.getServer(params["id"]); // Here with id as string
    }
  );
}
```

and in your

```
getServer(id: number) {
  const server = this.servers.find(
    (s) => {
      return s.id === id;
    }
  );
  return server;
}
```

you are doing a type strict check with `===` and thats the reason it is not able to find. You can replace `===` with `==` or call method with proper argument as below

`this.server = this.serversService.getServer(+params["id"])`

Comment: Thanks. I just added "+" before the second call and it works. But the subscribe method is called on an Observable (async) and it is not supposed to get called the first time the component gets loaded according to my instructor. I need to look it up. Thanks for the help.